Power Automate - How can I change the trigger frequency?
How can I change the frequency for a trigger in Power Automate?
No matter what I do, the frequency keeps getting reset to 5 Minutes.


You’ll find you can’t for some of these. Simple as that really.

the trigger frequency is tied to the Power Automate plan the account is licensed for. The costlier premium plans use a higher frequency than the plans included in M365.

The wake-up time depends on the license plan on which the flow runs.
For example, your flows may run every 15 minutes if you’re on the Free license plan. On the Free plan, if a cloud flow is triggered less than 15 minutes after its last run, it’s queued until 15 minutes have elapsed. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/triggers-troubleshoot?tabs=classic-designer#theres-a-delay-before-my-trigger-fires
